# Unit Test for content of PyQt.QTableView

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

My GUI (PyQt5, Python3.6) displays data from an SQLite database, mostly using QTableViews.

I'm unit-testing the application using defined input files, and I want to check whether everything is shown in the GUI at the right place. Now, all the data is in the model attached to the QTableView, not the QTableView itself. And I sometimes use `QTableView.hideRow()` to hide some of the columns which are present in the raw data but not desired to be shown in this particular view.

**How can I test that everything is displayed in the expected place *in the QTableView*?**

Here's a mini example class I'd like to write unit tests for:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtSql
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QTableView, QApplication, QHBoxLayout)
import sys

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(400, 150)

        self.createConnection()
        self.fillTable()
        self.createModel()
        self.initUI()

    def createConnection(self):
        self.db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        self.db.setDatabaseName("test.db")
        if not self.db.open():
            print("Cannot establish a database connection")
            return False

    def fillTable(self):
        self.db.transaction()
        q = QtSql.QSqlQuery()

        q.exec_("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cars;")
        q.exec_("CREATE TABLE Cars (Company TEXT, Model TEXT, Year NUMBER);")
        q.exec_("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES ('Honda', 'Civic', 2009);")
        q.exec_("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES ('VW', 'Golf', 2013);")
        q.exec_("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES ('VW', 'Polo', 1999);")

        self.db.commit()

    def createModel(self):
        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
        self.model.setTable("Cars")
        self.model.select()

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        view = QTableView()
        layout.addWidget(view)

        view.setModel(self.model)
        view.hideRow(1)

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        if (self.db.open()):
            self.db.close()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I can test the data in the model, of course:

```
self.assertEqual(model.headerData(0, Qt.Horizontal, Qt.DisplayRole), "Company")
self.assertEqual(model.data(model.index(0, 0), Qt.DisplayRole), "Honda")
```

etc.

But the *model* contains 3 rows, whereas my QTableView only has 2 (as the VW Golf row is hidden).

**So, is there a way to test the data as shown in the QTableView rather than the data in the model?** (In the example class, I want tests to assert that the view only contains 2 rows, and that the Polo row is the second.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to verify if any index is visible this does not depend on the model because a model is the representation of the data, for example a model can be shared by several views so each view chooses what items to show, to know which index are visible in a `QTableView` you must use the `isIndexHidden()` method:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtSql
import sys

class Example(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        layout.addWidget(self.view)

        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.view.hideRow(1)
        self.items_visible()

    def items_visible(self):
        for i in range(self.model.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.model.columnCount()):
                ix = self.model.index(i, j)
                if not self.view.isIndexHidden(ix):
                    print("{}-{}: {}".format(ix.row(), ix.column(), ix.data()))


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How about wanting to check that the Polo row is the second row displayed? As the row number in the view and the model are not the same, I find this difficult.

Comment: As indicated by a model can be shared by many views, so in some could filter certain columns, in others hide certain rows, etc, so the visualindex will not necessarily match the model's index.

Comment: [cont] That of visible is a bit vague, for example, let's say that you have 100 rows, and you have not used hideRow () so it could be said that all rows are visible but being many rows the scrollvar would make some rows hidden to the views, so to avoid confusion and loss of time, how do you define that a row is visible, and how do you number them

Comment: That's why I was looking to somehow test the data of the view itself, because each view shows a defined set of rows, so it should be possible to count from there. But if that's not possible, I'll have to make do by testing that all (and only) the non-hidden rows are not hidden, and the content of the non-hidden rows is ok. Seems ugly, but workable. Thanks for the pointer to isIndexHidden.

Comment: Is that the performance of the indexes that are displayed are not saved by performance, do not you think that saving the visualIndex leads to an unnecessary expenditure of memory ?, I already have several years working with Qt and I have never needed to obtain the visualIndex, so which I think is not necessary, it would only be a memory expense.

Comment: Tbh, I don't care overmuch about the performance of unit tests. But for refactoring  (e.g., changing the model underneath the views) it would have been great to have a test that makes sure that everything is still displayed correctly afterwards.